# wildcard subdomains on localhost

Tags: xampp, localhost, subdomain

So i have on my localhost (xampp) a site that is in development right now

http: // localhost/new_site/

**the site uses dynamic subdomains ... on the live server i mean ... and i need to replicate that on my localhost**
so http: // *.localhost/new_site/ should load http: // localhost/new_site/

*the solutions i found are for specific subdomains not for wildcards* most of them assume that u need one or two subdomains and that ur project is in the root of localhost.

so cand anyone suggest a solution?

thanks,
Rares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subdomains are simply DNS maps. You cannot map DNS on localhost, as localhost simply refers to your local loopback IP, whereas a subdomain referrs to a completely different IP in DNS.

To understand this better:

When you go to google.com, your browser queries a DNS server for what IP to connect to. If you go to maps.google.com, it will query it for a different IP, which in this case redirects to http://google.com/maps - therefore since localhost is simply 127.0.0.1, not a DNS reference, you cannot specify subdomain.localhost

Comment: Thats not fully true. Only "localhost" is a reserved name in DNS, while "*.localhost" is not reserved and can be configured in DNS to 127.0.0.1. We use that for local development.

Answer (score 4):

Wildcard (*) subdomain is not possible on localhost. However, for testing purpose, you can configure a few subdomains in your "**hosts**" file located at "**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**"

*In the example below, I have used **uniedu** instead of localhost*

```
127.0.0.1   uniedu
::1 uniedu

127.0.0.1 suba.uniedu subb.uniedu
::1     suba.uniedu subb.uniedu
```

> You can add multiple subs in a single entry by separating them with
> SPACE

IMPORTANT: You must also add the same subs in XAMP/WAMP by editing vhosts file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName uniedu
    ServerAlias suba.uniedu subb.uniedu
    DocumentRoot "e:/....
    ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I wouldn't quite agree with "not possible". See answer below...

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can create a local DNS server on your development machine and point your network DNS records to look up domains on your local machine. This means that when you type a domain name into your browser, the browser will ask your local DNS server before asking an external DNS server. You can then create custom zones (including *.localhost) on your local DNS server and then point that back to 127.0.0.1 or your local DHCP-issued IP address. I would suggest looking at DNSProxy:

> https://github.com/hubdotcom/marlon-tools - docs

or

> https://github.com/hubdotcom/marlon-tools/blob/master/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py - code

Alternatively check out DNSMasq:

> https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html - docs

or

> https://sixfeetup.com/blog/local-development-with-wildcard-dns-on-linux -tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use nip.io

if you type 192.168.0.5.nip.io it will resolve back to your IP, thus you got your DNS resolved.

Therefore for wildcard DNS john.192.168.0.5.nip.io also resolve to your IP , Therefore you can have an alias to your Apache or Nginx configuration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).